# Composer: How to remove #StandWithUkraine cli message?

Tags: composer-php

Regardless of personal political opinions, how would one opt out of the https://repo.packagist.org message:

```
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I try to keep the answer as neutral as possible. There used to be a very [lively discussion](https://web.archive.org/web/20221011212844/https://github.com/composer/composer/discussions/10808) on GitHub, which was censored/deleted by the team without warning.

There are a few options to remove the message:

**1. Configure a non political repository (by https://github.com/xieyuheng)**

choose from  https://packagist.org/mirrors, for example this Chinese server:

```
composer config -g repos.packagist composer https://mirrors.tencent.com/composer/
```

**2. Create an alias to remove the message on your cli (by https://github.com/ludo237 and others)**

On mac OS for me this one worked (saved inside the `~/.zshrc`):

```
alias composer="2> >(grep -av 'StandWith') composer --ansi "
```

It is not ideal, as it eats the eats the interactive bits, but is is most of the time pretty functioning.

**3. Create a patched version of Composer (by https://github.com/politsin)**

```
git clone https://github.com/composer/composer.git  ~/composer-build && \
    composer install  -o -d ~/composer-build && \
    wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/politsin/snipets/master/patch/composer.patch -q -O ~/composer-build/composer.patch  && \
    cd ~/composer-build && patch -p1 < composer.patch && \
    php -d phar.readonly=0 bin/compile && \
    rm /usr/local/bin/composer && \
    php composer.phar install && \
    php composer.phar update && \
    mv ~/composer-build/composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer && \
    rm -rf ~/composer-build  && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/composer
```

**History**

https://github.com/Seldaek the main driver of Composer and Packagist mentioned [here](https://github.com/composer/composer/discussions/11427), why he removed the original discussion.

Comment: [one more solution](https://en.anyquestion.info/a/eliminating-standwithukraine-cli-message-from-your-composer-a-how-to-guide) (not tested by me, but I can imagine it removed the colors)

Comment: Look like banner was removed from repository

Answer (score 5):

The message was removed from the solution.

> This message has been here for a long time now and I do not think it is having any effect anymore as every user has seen it many times. Removing it so I do not have to spend so much time and energy on tickets debating it anymore.
>
> - [Seldaek](https://github.com/Seldaek) (committed `2023-10-11T10:12:37Z`).

Source: [composer/packagist@d394c8d at main - GitHub](https://github.com/composer/packagist/commit/d394c8de05843d8f7789e6b37215c7a173590f5f)

---

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a small update for people using herd...
For your convenience, I've assembled it as a zsh function alias. You can put it in your .aliases or .bashrc or .zshrc or just take any part of it as you like. This is simply the solution from @politsin on github wrapped with a configuration variable that chooses herd, homebrew or any other service you are serving from to place your updated composer.

Once properly added to your environment, you would run this by typing `composer:purge-politics` into the terminal. It will do the rest. For peace of mind check the raw script yourself.

Cheers

```
composer:purge-politics() {
    # the keyword local destructs the memory variables so they wont stick around
    # after your function closes to interfere with any other system settings
    # which server are you going to run herd or something else (homebrew, xamp)
    local server="herd"
    local composer_path
    
    # choose the appropriate  path for composer
    [[ $server == "herd" ]] && composer_path="/Users/<your home directory>/Library/Application Support/Herd/bin/composer" || composer_path="/usr/local/bin/composer"
    # ** note change <your home directory>
 
    git clone https://github.com/composer/composer.git  ~/composer-build && \
    composer install  -o -d ~/composer-build && \
    wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/politsin/snipets/master/patch/composer.patch -q -O ~/composer-build/composer.patch  && \
    cd ~/composer-build && patch -p1 < composer.patch && \
    php -d phar.readonly=0 bin/compile && \
    rm /usr/local/bin/composer && \
    php composer.phar install && \
    php composer.phar update && \
    mv ~/composer-build/composer.phar "$composer_path" && \
    rm -rf ~/composer-build  && \
    chmod +x "$composer_path"
}
```